# Download Item With Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, download

I want to allow client to download attachment. Here `attachment.AttachmentContent` is bytes array from file. When I click on the button to download attachment it runs this code below. But I have the following script error. What should I do to fix it ?

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this
>   error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. Details:
>   Error parsing near '����JFIF``'.

```
Attachment attachment = _attachmentService.GetAttachmentBytesById(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "test.jpg" + "\"");
Response.OutputStream.Write(attachment.AttachmentContent, 0, attachment.AttachmentContent.Length);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you are sending this file download in partial response.

The most common cause if that your download button is inside an UpdatePanel.

Files can only be send on a full PostBack.

You can set your download button as a PostBack trigger to solve this.

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Download_Click">
</Triggers>
```