# PageRequestManagerParserErrorException for downloading after postback

Tags: asp.net, download, updatepanel, repeater

I have one `UpdatePanel` includes three`Repeater` in my `ascx` like below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%-- Info (Repeater 1)--%>
        <div id="info" class="tab-pane">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptInfo" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server"
                        ID="lnkSaveInfo"
                        CommandName="saveInfo"
                        ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>

        <%-- Documents (Repeater 2)--%>
        <div id="documents" class="tab-pane">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptDocumentDefs" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <%-- subDocuments (Repeater 3)--%>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptSubDocumnets" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptSubDocumnets_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptSubDocumnets_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr class="rgRow">
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server"
                                            ID="LnkDownLoadDocument"
                                            CommandName="downLoadDocument"
                                            ClientIDMode="AutoID">
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </table>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind**

```
public void rptSubDocumnets_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    ScriptManager scriptMan = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    scriptMan.RegisterPostBackControl(e.Item.FindControl("LnkDownLoadDocument") as LinkButton);
}
```

If I click on `LnkDownLoadDocument` then download file works correctly but if I click on `lnkSaveInfo` and after that I click on `LnkDownLoadDocument`, I get error like below:

> Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common
>   causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to
>   Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is
>   enabled. Details: Error parsing near '�PNG

I used download method in many projects and it works properly and there isn't any errors in server side when I am debugging my codes.

**None of solutions worked properly in my issue**

I tried many solutions that they are similar to my problem like below, but none of them worked properly and I decided that I ask new question.

[Download Item With Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038286/download-item-with-response)

[How to do AsyncPostBackTrigger for the LinkButton in the Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716362/how-to-do-asyncpostbacktrigger-for-the-linkbutton-in-the-repeater)

[Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221033/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-the-message-received-from-t)

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate method that loops all items in the Repeater and attach the PostBack trigger there.

```
private void bindPosdtBackToRepeaterButtons()
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptDocumentDefs.Items)
    {
        ScriptManager scriptMan = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        scriptMan.RegisterPostBackControl(item.FindControl("LnkDownLoadDocument") as LinkButton);
    }
}
```

Call this method in the `lnkSaveInfo` handler. You can also use this instead of the DataBound event to save some lines of code. Call this method after the Repeater `DataBind()` is executed.